# Implementation in Spring Webflux "works", but I'm trying to understand "why?"

Tags: java, functional-programming, spring-webflux

"You are thinking imperative, that first row will be executed then the second which is not the case in webflux. You have to think events-callbacks."

I agree with that assessment (I have A LOT of experience doing things "imperatively"), and hope that folks can help me with rudder-correction on how I'm viewing the solution-space. I am posting three different versions of the same "functionality", only one of which works (and, I'm open to comments on how that version could/should be modified to better align with reactive/functional implementation).

With the direction/help of the person making the quoted assessment, I was able to get *`DemoPOJOHandler.add(ServerRequest)'* working. The code, along with debug-level output, is shown below. What I note is that, right after the *HTTP POST "/v2/DemoPOJO"* and *"Mapped to mil.navy..." lines, there is an entry from *reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive* stating "*Subscribing inbound receiver..*". This seems to be the key action, missing from my other two attempts.

My specific (albeit "long'ish) question is:

I "get" that thinking that statement #1 will be executed, then statement #2, etc. is an "imperative" view of the solution space. But, in the example below, that appears to be the behavior that is happening. The *logger* statement is executing at 08:38:34.217, followed by the subscription at 08:38:34.251, which then instantiates a DemoPOJO at 08:39:34.267, and then everything "works".

But, the chaining in the *`request.bodyToMono()...`* sequence doesn't appear significantly different than the chaining of methods in imperative code (e.g., *'Integer.toString().indexOf()'*), with the exception of the lambdas (or, is the presence of lambdas the reason why "things change"?). So, if *`request.bodyToMono()...`* sequence, in theory, doesn't require the "*`.then()`*" or "*`.switchIfEmpty()`*", then why doesn't the core *`request.bodyToMono()...`* sequence execute "*`service.add(demoPOJO)`*"? I get that the Mono is not being subscribed to, but why does it seem like the additional statements in the chain are required for the subscription to happen and the POJO added to the repo?

This code executes successfully...

```
@Component
public class DemoPOJOHandler {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DemoPOJOHandler.class);

    @Autowired
    private DemoPOJOService service;

    public Mono<ServerResponse> add(ServerRequest request) {
        logger.debug("DemoPOJOHandler.add( ServerRequest )");

        return request.bodyToMono(DemoPOJO.class).doOnSuccess(demoPOJO -> service.add(demoPOJO))
                                                 .then(ServerResponse.ok().build())
                                                 .switchIfEmpty(ServerResponse.badRequest()
                                                                              .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                                                                              .build());
    }
}


2019-07-25 08:38:34.144 DEBUG 11992 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf          : -Dio.netty.buffer.checkAccessible: true
2019-07-25 08:38:34.145 DEBUG 11992 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf          : -Dio.netty.buffer.checkBounds: true
2019-07-25 08:38:34.145 DEBUG 11992 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] i.n.util.ResourceLeakDetectorFactory     : Loaded default ResourceLeakDetector: io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector@7a8a4d6a
2019-07-25 08:38:34.157 DEBUG 11992 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] r.n.http.server.HttpServerOperations     : [id: 0xa2da3d98, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:62644] New http connection, requesting read
2019-07-25 08:38:34.157 DEBUG 11992 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] r.n.http.server.HttpServerOperations     : [id: 0x5f552130, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:62645] New http connection, requesting read
2019-07-25 08:38:34.157 DEBUG 11992 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] reactor.netty.channel.BootstrapHandlers  : [id: 0x5f552130, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:62645] Initialized pipeline DefaultChannelPipeline{(BootstrapHandlers$BootstrapInitializerHandler#0 = reactor.netty.channel.BootstrapHandlers$BootstrapInitializerHandler), (reactor.left.httpCodec = io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpServerCodec), (reactor.left.httpTrafficHandler = reactor.netty.http.server.HttpTrafficHandler), (reactor.right.reactiveBridge = reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler)}
2019-07-25 08:38:34.157 DEBUG 11992 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.netty.channel.BootstrapHandlers  : [id: 0xa2da3d98, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:62644] Initialized pipeline DefaultChannelPipeline{(BootstrapHandlers$BootstrapInitializerHandler#0 = reactor.netty.channel.BootstrapHandlers$BootstrapInitializerHandler), (reactor.left.httpCodec = io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpServerCodec), (reactor.left.httpTrafficHandler = reactor.netty.http.server.HttpTrafficHandler), (reactor.right.reactiveBridge = reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler)}
2019-07-25 08:38:34.157 DEBUG 11992 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] io.netty.util.Recycler                   : -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread: 4096
2019-07-25 08:38:34.157 DEBUG 11992 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] io.netty.util.Recycler                   : -Dio.netty.recycler.maxSharedCapacityFactor: 2
2019-07-25 08:38:34.157 DEBUG 11992 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] io.netty.util.Recycler                   : -Dio.netty.recycler.linkCapacity: 16
2019-07-25 08:38:34.157 DEBUG 11992 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] io.netty.util.Recycler                   : -Dio.netty.recycler.ratio: 8
2019-07-25 08:38:34.173 DEBUG 11992 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] r.n.http.server.HttpServerOperations     : [id: 0x5f552130, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:62645] Increasing pending responses, now 1
2019-07-25 08:38:34.173 DEBUG 11992 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServer     : [id: 0x5f552130, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:62645] Handler is being applied: org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter@579c20c6
2019-07-25 08:38:34.195 DEBUG 11992 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [5f552130] HTTP POST "/v2/DemoPOJO"
2019-07-25 08:38:34.217 DEBUG 11992 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] o.s.w.r.f.s.s.RouterFunctionMapping      : [5f552130] Mapped to mil.navy.demo.DemoPOJO.DemoPOJORouter$$Lambda$258/1123559518@22a8277c
2019-07-25 08:38:34.217 DEBUG 11992 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] mil.navy.demo.DemoPOJO.DemoPOJOHandler   : DemoPOJOHandler.add( ServerRequest )
2019-07-25 08:38:34.251 DEBUG 11992 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive        : [id: 0x5f552130, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:62645] Subscribing inbound receiver [pending: 0, cancelled:false, inboundDone: false]
2019-07-25 08:38:34.267 DEBUG 11992 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] mil.navy.demo.DemoPOJO.DemoPOJO          : DemoPOJO.DemoPOJO( 666, foo_666, 10666 )
2019-07-25 08:38:34.267 DEBUG 11992 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] mil.navy.demo.DemoPOJO.DemoPOJO          : DemoPOJO.toString()
2019-07-25 08:38:34.267 DEBUG 11992 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] o.s.http.codec.json.Jackson2JsonDecoder  : [5f552130] Decoded [666 :: foo_666 :: 10666]
2019-07-25 08:38:34.267 DEBUG 11992 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] mil.navy.demo.DemoPOJO.DemoPOJOService   : DemoPOJOService.add( DemoPOJO )
2019-07-25 08:38:34.267 DEBUG 11992 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] mil.navy.demo.DemoPOJO.DemoPOJORepo      : DemoPOJORepo.add( DemoPOJO )
2019-07-25 08:38:34.267 DEBUG 11992 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] mil.navy.demo.DemoPOJO.DemoPOJO          : DemoPOJO.getId()
2019-07-25 08:38:34.267 DEBUG 11992 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] mil.navy.demo.DemoPOJO.DemoPOJO          : DemoPOJO.getId()
2019-07-25 08:38:34.267 DEBUG 11992 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] mil.navy.demo.DemoPOJO.DemoPOJORepo      : DemoPOJORepo.add( DemoPOJO ) -> adding for id 666
2019-07-25 08:38:34.267 DEBUG 11992 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] mil.navy.demo.DemoPOJO.DemoPOJO          : DemoPOJO.getId()
2019-07-25 08:38:34.272 DEBUG 11992 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [5f552130] Completed 200 OK
2019-07-25 08:38:34.273 DEBUG 11992 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] r.n.http.server.HttpServerOperations     : [id: 0x5f552130, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:62645] Last HTTP response frame
2019-07-25 08:38:34.273 DEBUG 11992 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] r.n.http.server.HttpServerOperations     : [id: 0x5f552130, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:62645] No sendHeaders() called before complete, sending zero-length header
2019-07-25 08:38:34.274 DEBUG 11992 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] r.n.http.server.HttpServerOperations     : [id: 0x5f552130, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:62645] Decreasing pending responses, now 0
2019-07-25 08:38:34.275 DEBUG 11992 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] r.n.http.server.HttpServerOperations     : [id: 0x5f552130, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:62645] Last HTTP packet was sent, terminating the channel
2019-07-25 08:38:41.720 DEBUG 11992 --- [169.254.211.161] sun.rmi.transport.tcp                    : RMI TCP Connection(4)-169.254.211.161: (port 62610) connection closed
2019-07-25 08:38:41.720 DEBUG 11992 --- [169.254.211.161] sun.rmi.transport.tcp                    : RMI TCP Connection(4)-169.254.211.161: close connection
```

This code executes "without errors", but never subscribes and so never executes the "*`doOnSuccess(...)`*" portion of the chain. But, it seems like it should? What is "magic" about chaining the separate *return...* statement onto the *'request.bodyToMono(...)'* statement with a "*.then(...)*"?

```
@Component
public class DemoPOJOHandler {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DemoPOJOHandler.class);

    @Autowired
    private DemoPOJOService service;

    public Mono<ServerResponse> add(ServerRequest request) {
        logger.debug("DemoPOJOHandler.add( ServerRequest )");

        request.bodyToMono(DemoPOJO.class).doOnSuccess(demoPOJO -> System.out.println("DEMO -> " + demoPOJO.toString()));
        return  ServerResponse.ok().build();
    }
}


2019-07-25 08:40:16.155 DEBUG 17064 --- [169.254.211.161] sun.rmi.transport.tcp                    : RMI TCP Connection(4)-169.254.211.161: (port 62661) connection closed
2019-07-25 08:40:16.155 DEBUG 17064 --- [169.254.211.161] sun.rmi.transport.tcp                    : RMI TCP Connection(4)-169.254.211.161: close connection
2019-07-25 08:40:18.248 DEBUG 17064 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf          : -Dio.netty.buffer.checkAccessible: true
2019-07-25 08:40:18.248 DEBUG 17064 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf          : -Dio.netty.buffer.checkBounds: true
2019-07-25 08:40:18.248 DEBUG 17064 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] i.n.util.ResourceLeakDetectorFactory     : Loaded default ResourceLeakDetector: io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector@3860465a
2019-07-25 08:40:18.266 DEBUG 17064 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] r.n.http.server.HttpServerOperations     : [id: 0x768a1f21, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:62695] New http connection, requesting read
2019-07-25 08:40:18.266 DEBUG 17064 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] r.n.http.server.HttpServerOperations     : [id: 0x51900c31, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:62696] New http connection, requesting read
2019-07-25 08:40:18.267 DEBUG 17064 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] reactor.netty.channel.BootstrapHandlers  : [id: 0x51900c31, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:62696] Initialized pipeline DefaultChannelPipeline{(BootstrapHandlers$BootstrapInitializerHandler#0 = reactor.netty.channel.BootstrapHandlers$BootstrapInitializerHandler), (reactor.left.httpCodec = io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpServerCodec), (reactor.left.httpTrafficHandler = reactor.netty.http.server.HttpTrafficHandler), (reactor.right.reactiveBridge = reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler)}
2019-07-25 08:40:18.267 DEBUG 17064 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] reactor.netty.channel.BootstrapHandlers  : [id: 0x768a1f21, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:62695] Initialized pipeline DefaultChannelPipeline{(BootstrapHandlers$BootstrapInitializerHandler#0 = reactor.netty.channel.BootstrapHandlers$BootstrapInitializerHandler), (reactor.left.httpCodec = io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpServerCodec), (reactor.left.httpTrafficHandler = reactor.netty.http.server.HttpTrafficHandler), (reactor.right.reactiveBridge = reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler)}
2019-07-25 08:40:18.273 DEBUG 17064 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] io.netty.util.Recycler                   : -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread: 4096
2019-07-25 08:40:18.273 DEBUG 17064 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] io.netty.util.Recycler                   : -Dio.netty.recycler.maxSharedCapacityFactor: 2
2019-07-25 08:40:18.273 DEBUG 17064 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] io.netty.util.Recycler                   : -Dio.netty.recycler.linkCapacity: 16
2019-07-25 08:40:18.273 DEBUG 17064 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] io.netty.util.Recycler                   : -Dio.netty.recycler.ratio: 8
2019-07-25 08:40:18.285 DEBUG 17064 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] r.n.http.server.HttpServerOperations     : [id: 0x51900c31, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:62696] Increasing pending responses, now 1
2019-07-25 08:40:18.289 DEBUG 17064 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServer     : [id: 0x51900c31, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:62696] Handler is being applied: org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter@7fa4fcbc
2019-07-25 08:40:18.297 DEBUG 17064 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [51900c31] HTTP POST "/v2/DemoPOJO"
2019-07-25 08:40:18.315 DEBUG 17064 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] o.s.w.r.f.s.s.RouterFunctionMapping      : [51900c31] Mapped to mil.navy.demo.DemoPOJO.DemoPOJORouter$$Lambda$262/1446001495@27a07cfc
2019-07-25 08:40:18.316 DEBUG 17064 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] mil.navy.demo.DemoPOJO.DemoPOJOHandler   : DemoPOJOHandler.add( ServerRequest )
2019-07-25 08:40:18.358 DEBUG 17064 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [51900c31] Completed 200 OK
2019-07-25 08:40:18.359 DEBUG 17064 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] r.n.http.server.HttpServerOperations     : [id: 0x51900c31, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:62696] Last HTTP response frame
2019-07-25 08:40:18.359 DEBUG 17064 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] r.n.http.server.HttpServerOperations     : [id: 0x51900c31, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:62696] No sendHeaders() called before complete, sending zero-length header
2019-07-25 08:40:18.360 DEBUG 17064 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] r.n.http.server.HttpServerOperations     : [id: 0x51900c31, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:62696] Decreasing pending responses, now 0
2019-07-25 08:40:18.361 DEBUG 17064 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] r.n.http.server.HttpServerOperations     : [id: 0x51900c31, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:62696] Last HTTP packet was sent, terminating the channel
2019-07-25 08:40:18.366 DEBUG 17064 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] r.n.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler     : [id: 0x51900c31, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:62696] No ChannelOperation attached. Dropping: 
         +-------------------------------------------------+
         |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|00000000| 7b 0a 20 20 20 20 22 69 64 22 3a 20 36 36 36 2c |{.    "id": 666,|
|00000010| 0a 20 20 20 20 22 6e 61 6d 65 22 3a 20 22 66 6f |.    "name": "fo|
|00000020| 6f 5f 36 36 36 22 2c 0a 20 20 20 20 22 76 61 6c |o_666",.    "val|
|00000030| 75 65 22 3a 20 31 30 36 36 36 0a 7d             |ue": 10666.}    |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
```

This code simply blows up with a NPE. My failed logic was "well, if "*doOnSuccess(...)*" was not happening because the *Mono* was not being subscribed to, then "subscribe". Obviously, that was not the solution. Less obvious (to me, at this point-in-time), is "why?".

```
@Component
public class DemoPOJOHandler {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DemoPOJOHandler.class);

    @Autowired
    private DemoPOJOService service;

    public Mono<ServerResponse> add(ServerRequest request) {
        logger.debug("DemoPOJOHandler.add( ServerRequest )");

        request.bodyToMono(DemoPOJO.class).doOnSuccess(demoPOJO -> System.out.println("DEMO -> " + demoPOJO.toString()))
                                          .subscribe();
        return  ServerResponse.ok().build();
    }
}


reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: java.lang.NullPointerException
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at mil.navy.demo.DemoPOJO.DemoPOJOHandler.lambda$add$2(DemoPOJOHandler.java:73) ~[classes/:na]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onComplete(MonoPeekTerminal.java:311) [reactor-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onComplete(Operators.java:1743) ~[reactor-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onComplete(Operators.java:1743) ~[reactor-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSingle$SingleSubscriber.onComplete(MonoSingle.java:155) ~[reactor-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.checkTerminated(FluxFlatMap.java:794) ~[reactor-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drainLoop(FluxFlatMap.java:560) ~[reactor-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drain(FluxFlatMap.java:540) ~[reactor-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onComplete(FluxFlatMap.java:426) ~[reactor-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.checkTerminated(FluxFlatMap.java:794) ~[reactor-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drainLoop(FluxFlatMap.java:560) ~[reactor-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drain(FluxFlatMap.java:540) ~[reactor-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onComplete(FluxFlatMap.java:426) ~[reactor-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.DrainUtils.postCompleteDrain(DrainUtils.java:131) ~[reactor-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.DrainUtils.postComplete(DrainUtils.java:186) ~[reactor-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapSignal$FluxMapSignalSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMapSignal.java:213) ~[reactor-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:136) ~[reactor-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:252) ~[reactor-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:136) ~[reactor-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]
at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.terminateReceiver(FluxReceive.java:390) ~[reactor-netty-0.8.9.RELEASE.jar:0.8.9.RELEASE]
at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.drainReceiver(FluxReceive.java:197) ~[reactor-netty-0.8.9.RELEASE.jar:0.8.9.RELEASE]
at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundComplete(FluxReceive.java:338) ~[reactor-netty-0.8.9.RELEASE.jar:0.8.9.RELEASE]
at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundComplete(ChannelOperations.java:350) [reactor-netty-0.8.9.RELEASE.jar:0.8.9.RELEASE]
at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.terminate(ChannelOperations.java:399) [reactor-netty-0.8.9.RELEASE.jar:0.8.9.RELEASE]
at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerOperations.cleanHandlerTerminate(HttpServerOperations.java:519) [reactor-netty-0.8.9.RELEASE.jar:0.8.9.RELEASE]
at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpTrafficHandler.operationComplete(HttpTrafficHandler.java:314) [reactor-netty-0.8.9.RELEASE.jar:0.8.9.RELEASE]

    (... lots of stuff deleted to fit posting constraints ...)

2019-07-25 10:44:43.212 DEBUG 10544 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] r.n.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler     : [id: 0xa62e89df, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:8080 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:64515] No ChannelOperation attached. Dropping: 
         +-------------------------------------------------+
         |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|00000000| 7b 0a 20 20 20 20 22 69 64 22 3a 20 36 36 36 2c |{.    "id": 666,|
|00000010| 0a 20 20 20 20 22 6e 61 6d 65 22 3a 20 22 66 6f |.    "name": "fo|
|00000020| 6f 5f 36 36 36 22 2c 0a 20 20 20 20 22 76 61 6c |o_666",.    "val|
|00000030| 75 65 22 3a 20 31 30 36 36 36 0a 7d             |ue": 10666.}    |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
2019-07-25 10:45:08.112 DEBUG 10544 --- [169.254.211.161] sun.rmi.transport.tcp                    : RMI TCP Connection(3)-169.254.211.161: (port 64485) connection closed
2019-07-25 10:45:08.112 DEBUG 10544 --- [169.254.211.161] sun.rmi.transport.tcp                    : RMI TCP Connection(3)-169.254.211.161: close connection
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since i was the one that you have quoted at the top im going to try to answer your questions.

First we need to talk about "non-blocking". What is "non-blocking"? well non-blocking is event based. The underlying server, Netty, does not work with assigning one thread to each request but instead work with chain of events and event queues.

So when someone subscribes, netty will set up an underlying event queue (sort of) that will basically work as:

```
x <- y <- z
```

To get x we need to resolve y, but to get y we need to resolve z. This is what people usually refer to as the "functional" part in this type of programming.

One of the most common misstakes i see when people start with reactive programming is that they don't understand that the `subscriber` is the calling `client`. Your spring application is the `publisher` and every `client` calling your service is the `subscriber`.

**You should never subscribe in your application**

why would your publishing application subscribe to itself? when you explain it that way people usually understand.

So lets look at your examples and i'll take them in reverse order:

**Example 3:**

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> add(ServerRequest request) {
    logger.debug("DemoPOJOHandler.add( ServerRequest )");

    request.bodyToMono(DemoPOJO.class).doOnSuccess(demoPOJO -> System.out.println("DEMO -> " + demoPOJO.toString()))
                                      .subscribe();
    return  ServerResponse.ok().build();
}
```

Here we enter the method in a imperative way, we give it the request, The ServerRequest is a concrete object but as soon as you do `bodyToMono` you will return a `Mono<DemoPOJO>` which in turn is a wrapped `CompletableFuture` that inside has a computation (to take the body in the request and put it in your dto)

As soon as this computation is done the `Mono` will go into a `success` state and trigger what is after in the chain, so the `doOnSuccess` will get triggered. When `doOnSuccess` is done it will return `Mono<Void>`.

This is where your problem is when `doOnSuccess` has finished, you `subscribe`. So what you are doing here is that as soon as someone posts a `ServerRequest` to your application Netty (the server) will set up an event-chain and in this event-chain the application will subscribe to itself.

Here the chain is completed by the application subscribing to itself. So the application is its own client.

**Example 2:**

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> add(ServerRequest request) {
    logger.debug("DemoPOJOHandler.add( ServerRequest )");

    request.bodyToMono(DemoPOJO.class).doOnSuccess(demoPOJO -> System.out.println("DEMO -> " + demoPOJO.toString()));
    return  ServerResponse.ok().build();
}
```

Here we do the same as in example 3 it's just that when the event chain is set up, the request is mapped to a DTO, then we do something in the `doOnSuccess` but then the chain is broken. `doOnSuccess` signals that it is done, but nothing after is listening.

So here the event chain is broken, it is incomplete. Nothing happens until you subscribe, but since the chain is broken, no one can `subscribe` hence nothing will happen.

**Example 1:**

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> add(ServerRequest request) {
    logger.debug("DemoPOJOHandler.add( ServerRequest )");

    return request.bodyToMono(DemoPOJO.class).doOnSuccess(demoPOJO -> service.add(demoPOJO))
                                             .then(ServerResponse.ok().build())
                                             .switchIfEmpty(ServerResponse.badRequest()
                                                                          .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                                                                          .build());
}
```

Here the chain is complete. Something is signalling something, that is signalling something, when something is completed the next thing will trigger, and next, and next, and next.

The calling client posts data, the server sets up the eventchain, the chain is completed so that the client subscribes client subscribes and then the event chain starts and triggers all the callbacks and returns data.

`Flux<T>` and `Mono<T>` are both wrapper classes around the monad `CompletableFuture<T>`. `Optional<T>` and `Stream<T>` are also monads and monads come from the functional world like the programming language Haskell. A good way to understand how they work is to learn more about monads.

If you want to in general understand more about monads im going to shamelessly plug my own article about it:

[Write a Monad, in Java, seriously?](https://medium.com/swlh/write-a-monad-in-java-seriously-50a9047c9839)

I good read is also the [Intro to reactive programming](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#intro-reactive) i recommend going through all their examples.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to address my questions. In honesty, I consider myself a fairly decent s/w engineer, but have never been a fan of using "other people's code"...just because it requires understanding how it's supposed to be used. With Webflux and Reactor, though...well, it's "another story" and I'm experiencing a steep learning curve.

Comment: No worries, it’s hard. I started learning the functional language Haskell a couple of years ago, its hard at first but gets easier and easier.